# Как в pandas получить максимум исключая некоторые из столбцов из вычислений?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, статистика

Есть матрица корреляций. 
Мне нужно получить максимум игнорируя определенные столбцы. 
Для этого я присоединил к матрице еще один столбец с метками в качестве фильтра для фильтрации таких столбцов.

Задача вычислить максимум, исключая из расчета строки, где в столбце "CLASS" стоит единица. Поскольку матрица квадратная, столбец "CLASS" можно использовать и как строку.

Ниже код моей реализации. Он работает правильно, но очень медленно на больших таблицах! Помогите найти быстрый способ векторного вычисления средствами pandas. У меня не хватает памяти для работы с большими датафреймами с таким подходом.

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://st.storeland.ru/9/2418/212/demo10.csv', sep=';', index_col=0)
def noise_porog(Series_cor):
  noise_list = list()
  priznaki = list(df['CLASS'])
  CLASS = 1

  for idx, crl in enumerate(Series_cor[:-1]):
    if priznaki[idx] != CLASS:
      noise_list.append(Series_cor[idx]) # список шумов
    else:
      pass

  return pd.Series(max(noise_list))

df['max_01'] = df.apply(noise_porog, axis=1)
```

Вот скрин для наглядности. Я выделил первую итерацию, где выбираю нужные столбцы и из них получаю максимум и записываю в новый столбец "max_01":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот матрица большего размера:

```html
df = pd.read_csv('https://st.storeland.ru/6/2418/067/demo.csv', sep=',', index_col=-1)
df = df.loc[:, ~df.columns.str.contains('unnamed', case=False)].T
df
```

Для удобства я сделал значения из "CLASS" в качестве названия столбцов.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте так:

```
df = pd.read_csv('https://st.storeland.ru/9/2418/212/demo10.csv', sep=';', index_col=0)
mask = df['CLASS']!=1
df['max_01'] = df.loc[:, df.columns.drop('CLASS',1)[mask]].max(axis=1)
```

Результат:

```
In [63]: df
Out[63]:
           2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10        11  CLASS    max_01
2   0.000000  0.107562  0.202508  0.082104  0.099218  0.166363 -0.138255 -0.030342  0.040025  0.236721      0  0.236721
3   0.107562  0.000000  0.069416  0.213758  0.167404  0.137428 -0.048976  0.056551  0.039009  0.270039      1  0.270039
4   0.202508  0.069416  0.000000  0.056688  0.302428  0.090878  0.032381  0.120947  0.414783  0.117498     -1  0.414783
5   0.082104  0.213758  0.056688  0.000000  0.247694  0.171819 -0.028765  0.157801  0.184200  0.465918      0  0.465918
6   0.099218  0.167404  0.302428  0.247694  0.000000 -0.096407 -0.184963  0.198542  0.222838  0.190360     -1  0.302428
7   0.166363  0.137428  0.090878  0.171819 -0.096407  0.000000  0.056020  0.144441  0.105880  0.119886     -1  0.171819
8  -0.138255 -0.048976  0.032381 -0.028765 -0.184963  0.056020  0.000000 -0.051127  0.027271 -0.050593      0  0.056020
9  -0.030342  0.056551  0.120947  0.157801  0.198542  0.144441 -0.051127  0.000000  0.212784 -0.019487      1  0.212784
10  0.040025  0.039009  0.414783  0.184200  0.222838  0.105880  0.027271  0.212784  0.000000  0.146514     -1  0.414783
11  0.236721  0.270039  0.117498  0.465918  0.190360  0.119886 -0.050593 -0.019487  0.146514  0.000000     -1  0.465918
```

PS лучше не добавлять столбец `CLASS` в качестве столбца DataFrame'а, а просто хранить его отдельно в виде `numpy.ndarray` или как `Pandas.Series`.

Comment: Спасибо! Насколько я понял, ваше решение просто находит максимум, но мне нужно научиться исключать некоторые столбцы из расчетов используя условие. Как например посчитать максимум по столбцам, индекс которых делится на 3 без остатка? - (под условие попадают столбцы 3, 6, и 9).

Comment: @Mavar, под индексом вы подразумеваете порядковый номер столбца или его имя?

Comment: имя столбца. У меня матрица в несколько десятков тысяч строк. И мне нужно на основе какого-то условия считать максимумы.

Comment: Простите за путанное пояснение. Столбец, который вы удаляете "CLASS" - является маской. Я его накладываю на матрицу и на основе его значений выбираю, в каких именно строках считать максимум или какие пропускать. Попробуйте заменить названия столбцов на значения из столбца CLASS.

Comment: @Mavar, а разве в ответе что-то другое?

Comment: iloc[:, 2::3] - Это верное решение, но я не могу так выбирать столбцы. В моей матрице названия столбцов не имеют закономерности. Я добавил более крупную матрицу и заменил названия колонок значениями из "CLASS". Мне нужно считать построчно максимумы, пропуская столбцы с названием "1". (названия столбцов для пропуска нужно задавать в переменной)

Comment: я нашел вот такой оператор `df.loc[:, ~df.columns.contains('1')]` , но он как-то странно фильтрует. Ожидал получить все столбцы, которые не содержат в названии столбца `1`. Но выводит столбца, в названии которых только `-1`

Comment: @Mavar, лучше задать отдельный вопрос, если хотите спросить как работает `df.columns.contains`